# facing issues during saving annotations in CVAT tool

Tags: annotations, cvat

I am getting an error when I try to save my polygon annotation in CVAT tool.

error: Could not save annotations [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpAUS.jpg)

I am trying to do annotations of my images in polygon shape for object detection.